# Item pairing from two text files

Tags: text-files, cracking

I need to pair two text files, One file contains User:Hash and the other file contains Hash:Pass I want a 3rd text file created containing User:Pass based on  matching Pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Hash-Killer has some awesome tools meant to split hashes and passwords.

https://hashkiller.co.uk/list-tool.aspx

or

alternatively you could use REGEX that is the method that they use to provide the "text tool"

PS: I know this from personally cracking hashes, and it can be a pain to sort out. regex would be a good option.